# What is the difference between these for loops?

Tags: c++

This is the code that gives the correct answer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    string str[] = {"","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};
    int a,b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    for(int i = a; i <= b; i++){ //this is the line i'm having a problem with I can't understand it

        if(i <= 9)cout << str[i] << endl;
        else{
            if(!(i%2))cout << "even" << endl;
            else cout << "odd" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code that I have written :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int n[2];
cin >> n[0] >> n[1];

for (int i = 0;i<=1;i++){
    if (n[i] == 1)
        cout << "one" <<endl;
    else if (n[i] == 2)
        cout << "two" <<endl;
    else if (n[i] == 3)
        cout << "three" <<endl;
    else if (n[i] == 4)
        cout << "four" <<endl;
    else if (n[i] == 5)
        cout << "five" <<endl;
    else if (n[i] == 6)
        cout << "six" <<endl;
    else if (n[i] == 7)
        cout << "seven" <<endl;
    else if (n[i] == 8)
        cout << "eight" <<endl;
    else
        cout << "nine" <<endl;
}

for (int i = 0 ; i <=1 ; i++){
     if (n[i] % 2 == 0)
            cout << "even" <<endl;
     else
            cout << "odd" <<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

I feel it's the same but I can't see where is the problem

the input sample should be two integers, seperated by newline

```
8
11
```

a positive number with a <= b

and the output will be

if it's <= 9, the number in english
but if it's > 9 then it will print whether it's even or odd

something like

```
eight
nine
even
odd
```

shouldn't the 1st code gives this output:

```
eight
nine
nine
nine
even
odd
even
odd
```

check this link : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/c-tutorial-for-loop/problem

wait I think I get it now so this snippet of code :

```
int a,b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    for(int i = a; i <= b; i++){ //this is the line i'm having a problem with I can't understand it

        if(i <= 9)cout << str[i] << endl;
        else{
            if(!(i%2))cout << "even" << endl;
            else cout << "odd" << endl;
        }
    }
```

will print out the numbers from a to b (*p.s i thought it will skip the numbers till it gets to the b because the sample input was 8 , 11 and the sample output wasn't clear anyways..)
but anything greater than 9 or 9 will print out nine in letters then after it it will print if it's even or odd..

sorry i didn't get it but thanks to you I understood it :)

```
for (int i = 0;i<=1;i++){
    if (n[i] == 1)
        cout << "one" <<endl;
    else if (n[i] == 2)
        cout << "two" <<endl;
    else if (n[i] == 3)
        cout << "three" <<endl;
    else if (n[i] == 4)
        cout << "four" <<endl;
    else if (n[i] == 5)
        cout << "five" <<endl;
    else if (n[i] == 6)
        cout << "six" <<endl;
    else if (n[i] == 7)
        cout << "seven" <<endl;
    else if (n[i] == 8)
        cout << "eight" <<endl;
    else
        cout << "nine" <<endl;
}

for (int i = 0 ; i <=1 ; i++){
     if (n[i] % 2 == 0)
            cout << "even" <<endl;
     else
            cout << "odd" <<endl;
}
```

the other snippet of code will do something different it will take a and b then print them out but if b is greater than 9 or 9 it will will print nine in letters and then checks if the numbers entered by the user a , b even or odd ..

that's a whole different thing sorry for that it was my first question i hope i get better with this thank you so much all loved being here.

Comment: What is weird about the for loop? Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: What's weird about the condition? And it will go through the numbers between a and b.

Comment: If those are weird, what would be a *normal* for-loop for you?

Comment: i meant tracing my original code seemed right till i run it..

Comment: the other code i found has this i = a , i <=b and i don't understand the use of it

Comment: **Input Format**

You will be given two positive integers, a and b (a <= b), separated by a newline.

**Output Format**

For each integer n in the interval [a,b] :

If 1 <= n <= 9, then print the English representation of it in lowercase. That is "one" for 1, "two" for 2, and so on.
Else if n > 9 and it is an even number, then print "even".
Else if n > 9 and it is an odd number, then print "odd".
Note: [a,b] = {x ∈ Z | a <= x <= b} = {a,a+1,...,b}.

sample input:

    8
    11

sample output:

    eight
    nine
    even
    odd

Comment: Please post your complete code, the snippet you posted is incomplete (and commented out). It seems like you are misunderstanding how the for loop and `(n[i] == 8)` works.

Comment: i'm really sorry guys it's my first time to be on here

Comment: It's ok, it's good to see people trying to learn. Where is `n` coming from? Please include the *entire* `main` function from your code.

Comment: ok the     n i made as an array of size 2 and asked the user for it

Comment: help please ???

Comment: Be patient. I have edited your question for clarity. I am busy right now, but I will be back if someone does not answer in a few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is the line I'm having a problem with
>
> ```
>     for(int i = a; i <= b; i++) { /* body of the loop */ }
> ```

See e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for, it translates into something like:

Executes `int i = a;` once, then executes the body of the loop and `i++` repeatedly, until the value of condition `i <= b` becomes false. The test takes place *before* each iteration.

So, basically, it defines an integer variable `i`, initializes it with the value of `a` and while its value is less than or equal to `b` it executes the body of the loop and increments `i`.

Now consider the text of the assignment:

> You will be given two positive integers, a and b (a <= b), separated by a newline.
>   [...] **For each integer n in the interval [a,b]** :

That's the first logic difference between your implementation and the accepted one. Consider this lines:

```
// The use of an array instead of two different variables is not a problem, but...
int n[2];
cin >> n[0] >> n[1];

// The loop is executed only twice, only for the two ends values, not the values in between
for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) { 
//          ^^^     ^^^ 
    if (n[i] == 1)
        cout << "one" << endl;
    else if (n[i] == 2)
    // ...
}
```

The correct way to loop *"for each integer in the interval [a,b]"*, given your array of two values, would be

```
for (int i = n[0]; i <= n[1]; i++) { 
//          ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^ 
    if (i == 1)
    // ^^^     
        cout << "one" << endl;
    else if (i == 2)
    //      ^^^
    // ...
}
```

The second one is that you have **two** loops, so each one is executed for each value, printing two strings, while you should have **one** loop and print one line for each value:

```
for (int i = n[0]; i <= n[1]; i++) { 
//          ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^ 
    if (i == 1)
        cout << "one" << endl;
    else if (i == 2)

// ...

    else if (i == 9)
//      ^^^^
        cout << "nine" << endl;
    else if (i % 2)
//  ^^^^^^^^        
        cout << "odd" <<endl;
    else
        cout << "even" <<endl;  
}
```

Comment: so if i get that right because actually i didn't lol so this code for the loop i said i'm having problem understanding will execute from a to b ?? then why it doesn't print all the numbers between 8 and 11 ..?!

Comment: another thing how did you add after ```else if ( i ==9 )``` another else if ?! if any other else if or even the first if executes then that ```else if (i % 2)``` won't work or that else! so can you explain more?! how can i have one loop

Comment: @xtcPanda I'm not sure how to explain it more clearly. Try to follow these incremental steps: [1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gkA8SS5DEWFbz0HN), [2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/h2xIxAet7KDhDTXe), [3](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KPgaTL91sFd2v6KM), [4](https://wandbox.org/permlink/peBgAiMuf5IzgXnt), ... [5](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1veYQeBrvfjGnJMy)

Comment: I know what is a loop and i can trace it Im a student in computer science level 2 now and i got a certificate in c++ done some basic things with it i can trace the code lol but if you tried the first code it won't do a loop from 8 to 11 like 8 9 10 11 it will just print 8 and 11 and the second loop will do that also 8 and 11 only but the problem is that the 2 snippet of code does work for me but on some cases it doesn't on hackrrank check this link( https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/c-tutorial-for-loop/problem )

Answer (score 0):

```
//str is an array with 10 items
cin >> a >> b;
for(int i = a; i <= b; i++){ //this is the line i'm having a problem with I can't understand it

    if(i <= 9)cout << str[i] << endl;
    else{
        if(!(i%2))cout << "even" << endl;
        else cout << "odd" << endl;
    }
}
```

The text at `str[i]` is only output if the user enters values of `a,b` such that `a < i < b`

Only some strings are output, depending on `a,b`.

"even" and "odd" are only output if `i >= 10`

```
cin >> n[0] >> n[1];
for (int i = 0;i<=1;i++){
    if (n[i] == 1)
        cout << "one" <<endl;
    else if (n[i] == 2)
        ... lines skipped
    else
        cout << "nine" <<endl;
}

for (int i = 0 ; i <=1 ; i++){
     if (n[i] % 2 == 0)
            cout << "even" <<endl;
     else
            cout << "odd" <<endl;
}
```

Some string "one", "two", etc is always ouput. The worst case, no coincidences, outputs "nine".

"even" or "odd" is output for the two user inputs.

Comment: umm not what i meant but i feel you can help me see n[i] is defined before as int n[2];
but this isn't my problem the problem is or my issue is that the first code with str variable doesn't print anything between a and b for some reason and as i understand the for loop it should now my question is these 2 ways answers the same question and the second is just long but do the trick the first should produce an error why !! it doesn't !!